# My OSX is saying "TorBrowserBundle_en-US" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I've downloaded the TBB but it won't open because "TorBrowserBundle_en-US" is from an "unidentified developer". How do I solve this?

Comment: "Unidentified developer" happens when the .app hasn't been signed by a code-signing cert. Tor would have to register for a code-signing cert from Apple (pay apple). Instead, Tor signs with GPG. On the download page, you see a little link to "sig" just below the download button, to download an ASC file. You must ensure you get the installer, and the sig asc file, from an HTTPS connection, directly from www.torproject.org. (Don't accept any URL that doesn't start with `https://www.torproject.org`). Then [verify the gpg signature](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en).

Comment: Note that it says `WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature! There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.` This is *not* ok. The [verify gpg signature](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) page says *This means that GnuPG verified that the key made that signature, but it's up to you to decide if that key really belongs to the developer. The best method is to meet the developer in person and exchange key fingerprints.* Since that's unrealistic, you must manually compare signature fingerprints (first the primary key, and then one

Comment: of the subkeys) listed on [the verify gpg signature page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en), matches the key fingerprints that were displayed by your `gpg --verify` command.

Comment: I wrote all the above comments as comments, instead of an answer, because this topic is protected, and I don't have permission to post an answer.

Comment: After manually verifying the GPG signature of TorBrowser.app, *do not* change your security preferences to "allow apps downloaded from anywhere." Instead, allow that *one particular* app to run, by opening System Preferences > Security & Privacy, and clicking "Open anyway" for "TorBrowser.app", or by right-clicking TorBrowser.app and going to "Open" so you can override the security settings for that one app.

Comment: Effectively, there is not much point in verifying the GPG signature of TorBrowser.app. As long as you download from `https://www.torproject.org`, if someone was able to tamper with the binary, they could probably also tamper with the *verify gpg signature* page, to tamper with the key fingerprints.

Answer (score 9):

With some security configurations Apple's operating systems will refuse to run any application they haven't specifically vetted by Apple Corp.

You can get around this easily.

From [Apple's OSX 10.8 support document](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11436):

> You can choose to override your security settings and open the app
>   anyway.
>
> In the Finder, locate the app you want to open. Most apps can be found in the Applications folder.
>   Press the Control-key and click the app icon.
>   Choose Open from the pop-up menu.
>   Click Open.

(The [Mac OSX 10.9 support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14369) has the same suggestion)

Reminder: any executable file from the internet is subject to tampering. Be sure to [verify the gpg signature](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) of the Tor file you downloaded before running it. Apple's [Gatekeeper program](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/) (the feature that blocks the initial running of Tor) is designed to help ease the process of verifying binaries for most users but for third parties who are not registered (like the Tor foundation) it results in extra hassle.

Comment: related - see http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/why-is-the-tor-foundation-registered-in-apples-gatekeeper-developer-id-program

Comment: So one can't add the Tor Project's GnuPG key to Gatekeeper? As with Linux aptitude, for example.

Comment: @mirimir - even if you could add user specified keys to Gatekeeper, it would not be a good idea to trust a third-party proprietary tool from a company subject to U.S. law to vet your binaries.

Comment: If one trusts Apple enough to use their OS, trusting Gatekeeper to properly check signed binaries doesn't seem like too much of a stretch ;)

Comment: "Unidentified developer" does not mean anything about Apple "vetting" the developer. If you have a code signing certificate, and distribute signed code, you are an identified developer. The process to get a code signing cert is similar to getting an SSL cert, which https://torproject.org clearly has. The TorBrowser.app should be signed. I want to know why it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to reset the policy to "Apple only" (or whatever it was) afterward.
The other answer is also wrong, it is fully possible to run what you develop with Xcode and also the Android Studio. 
Use System Preferences is a simple and easy way to do this. And of course you can download a key and patch it in manually also - but use the method that Apple endorses.
The reason for this is to enable them to halt you should you try to launch something that someone else has managed to download on your Mac, and even created an icon - this is NOT MICROSOFT WINDOWS and we don´t want those policies!

Answer (score -1):

Open system preferences, then security & privacy, and then enable the "anywhere" option in general settings.

Comment: While your answer might be technically correct, it doesn't discuss any pitfalls. So what downside has enabling this settings? Is it safe to do? Your answer should include more information. Please have a look at [how to write good answers](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).